# Need more than 50 Sharing Rules - now what?

Tags: security, limits, sharing-rule

**The Requirement:** Our organisation works in ~30 countries and has 6 groupings of workers ("Core Competencies") within each country. We have a number of Objects with OWD = Private and we need to restrict record access to users who only have access to the Projects where the Country__c and Core_Competency__c = the User's Country & Core Competency.

**The Problem:** 30 countries x 6 Core Competencies = 180 groupings of Users that we need to open up access via Sharing Rules. Since Salesforce has a limit of 50 criteria-based sharing rules, we're in a pickle.

**The Ask:** What is the best approach for satisfying this requirement? Do we need to use Apex sharing or Flow, or am I missing something else obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try calling sfdc support to see if they can expand the limit?

Comment: @cropredy I have not, but since this is a documented Salesforce Limit, like the number of fields on an Object, I am 99.9% sure they won't be able to expand this limit. Especially since I would need to almost quadruple the limit, not just expand it a little bit.

Comment: @JustinF Running into a similar challenge myself right now and found this post. See this kb [Increase the number of sharing rules per entity](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321647&type=1) which allows an org to increase the total to 500. It doesn't say anything about raising the limit on criteria based rules, only the total. But, it might indicate it's possible if you can provide sufficient justification to support your use case.

Comment: @crmprogdev I'd also explore territory-based sharing or hierarchy-based sharing.

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it thought but can't imagine convincing the client to implement territories for this particular use case. That would be a huge amount of overhead to support sharing records to Community Plus license users. We have all the roles and hierarchies we need. It's truly an object limitation we're facing. But, I'll lay it out to see if it would work to provide the grouping of accounts. Might mean another territory with every 12-16 new business accounts. Yuck!

Comment: @crmprogdev apex manual sharing?

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for the thought. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. LOL!